# Can't open http site in https?

Tags: php, web-services, http, https

I am  beginner in web development, i am  trying to open my web site in  https://eaxample.com but it not opening . it is working fine in http://eaxample.com . what should in need to do and why it's happening. please guide me to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends upon the web server (Apache, Lighttpd, ...) and its *configuration*

Comment: I downvoted the question because I think a simple Google search could help you more.

Comment: Ya, I know  Markus, But I didn't satisfy with that answers. any how thanks for your response.

Comment: Also this are the basics of web development. IF you are beginner than be very careful while installing the SSL certificate. Refer this link which describes step by step installation of all the different kind of OS/servers SSL installation http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTPS needs SSL certificates installed on your server.
You need to contact your hosting company for SSL certificates.

Comment: Please notice that this is affected with additional costs.

Comment: I'd like to add that this is true for production websites, but using a self-signed certificate is perfectly appropriate during development stages.